# Вывод переменной python 2.7

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

Мой селект

```
cur2 = con.cursor()
cur2.execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM all_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'mytable' order by column_id")
res = cur2.fetchall()
print(res[0])
```

Мой insert:

```
test= """INSERT INTO mytable(res[0], res[1], res[2])
    values (TO_DATE(:1, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), :2, :3)"""
```

Не могу вывести переменные в запросе res.

Answer (score 1):

ЕМНИП `cur2.fetchall()` вернёт генератор, а не список, поэтому лучше сделать так:

```
cur2.execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM all_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'mytable' order by column_id")
for row in cur2.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

если вам нужна только одна запись:

```
row = cur2.fetchone()
```

Comment: Почему не `[print(row) for row in cur2.fetchall()]`?

Comment: @Victor, в данном случае можно и `list(cur2.fetchall())` использовать, но обычно в цикле идет какая-нибудь обработка...

Comment: А ну вообще да. Извиняюсь за наезд :)